# Where to put Java 9's module descriptor file?

Tags: java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

Say I have a directory structure like:

```
src
+- main
   +- org.linuxdeveloper.space
      +- app
          +- Main.java
```

---

And **module-info.java**:

```
module example.module {
    requires jdk.unsupported;
}
```

If only `Main.java` requires the module `jdk.unsupported` to function. Should I put module-info.java in the `app` directory, or in `org.linuxdeveloper.space` or in the source root?

---

*Content below no longer is necessary for the question.*

**Note:**
I  use `jdk.internal.misc.SharedSecrets` in my module which is not exported by default.

**Update**:
Found StackWalker API, and will use that instead of SharedSecrets.

Comment: [Quick-start](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) should really solve this one for you and using an IDE most of them I believe would preferably ensure the presence of the module-info.java within the `src` folder(marked as sources root) structure.

Comment: All classes require `java.base`, implicitly.

Comment: @Holger please see the updated post.

Comment: Holger is correct, `requires java.base` is not needed here, irrespective of whether you are attempting to use JDK internal classes in java.base or not. I realize it's slightly off top-topic but it would be interesting to know what you are doing as any direct use of classes in jdk.internal.misc is fragile and will likely break from release to release. If you are looking for Unsafe then it's in sun.misc.Unsafe (module jdk.unsupported).

Comment: @AlanBateman Since misc.SharedSecrets is being removed, I'm trying to use  jdk.internal.misc.SharedSecrets instead.

Comment: jdk.internal.misc.SharedSecrets should never be used by code outside the JDK. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @AlanBateman trying to upgrade this to: https://github.com/javapathfinder/jpf-core/blob/master/src/main/gov/nasa/jpf/vm/HashedAllocationContext.java#L85 .. Java 9

Comment: Have you looked at java.lang.StackWalker API?